# Best way to handle Pandas Dataframe in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, flask

I have a flask application which reads a csv file using `pandas` and it returns some data after reading. There is no manipulation done to the `dataframe`. I have the `dataframe` stored in a `pickle` format so for every request that comes in, the application `unpickles` the file and reads data and returns it to the client.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import pandas as pd
import os
import json

@application.route('/Getdata', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
@Validate_API_Key
def index():
    fid = request.args.get('Fid', default=0, type=int)
    df = pd.read_pickle(os.getenv('DFFileName'), compression='gzip')
    res = get_fid_data(fid, df)
    data = res.to_dict(orient='records')
    return jsonify(data=data)
```

This is how the `get_fid_data()` is set up

```
def get_fid_data(fid, df):
    frecord = pd.DataFrame()

    # certain rows are selected from df based on fid and the
    # rows are appended to frecord. The frecord is then returned.

    return frecord
```

My question is, is there a way to make the the `df` global after reading it initially? It seems like `unpickling` the df for every request is unnecessary if its possible to "persist" the dataframe in memory for as long as the flask application is running. I'd like to have this so that for every request that comes in I can read the `df` from memory rather than reading the file.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/1154

Also this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644715/pandas-as-fast-data-storage-for-flask-application

Comment: thanks. Seems like I can read the file in the `@application.before_first_request()` and cache that. I'll give that a try

Comment: @sagar1025 you can create a `module` with `df initialisation`. just an example `df1 = pd.read_pickle(....) blablabla... df2 = pd.read_csv(....)blabla..`. in your api: `from your_module import df1`

Comment: Interesting @DanilaGanchar Will df1 be something "global" after its import? Can it be used directly inside routes?

Comment: @IoaTzimas you are using other functions/instances inside routes (`abort`, `jsonify` etc) ;)

Comment: Yeah probably your are right. I was suprised because it looks a very elegant solution to store repetitive data, and i haven't seen it again in suggestions in similar questions.

Comment: @IoaTzimas true for your case. because you have no dependencies on the application configuration or other instances

Comment: What about the risks of common global objects? Do they exist in such case? We can simply assign the df globally inside the app (which is not recommended because of risks). Is there any difference between this and the import from other file regarding risks?

Comment: @IoaTzimas I believe that for your case, a standalone `module` with all the necessary `datasets` will be more clear and understandable solution. Moreover, it will not depend on the application level(`Flask`, `context` etc). Also you can easily `mocks` a `module` for `tests`. From my experience I can say that it is better to have less dependencies from `Flask`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar that sounds like a clean way of doing it. No cache overhead or expiring to worry about. It's a nice alternative to caching!

Comment: @sagar1025 by the way you can move other functions(such as `def get_fid_data(fid: int) -> list`) into your `module`. not sure if you will have a lot of code there. anyway you can create more modules if you need a lot of functions for `datasets` processing. also you can easily write `unittests`. Plus you can easily replace `Flask` with anything in future - your modules and tests will works fine.